# Where are the manifest of an asp .net web site located?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-applications

I need to find a way to configure the manifest of a website in order to change the version number or add a redirection binding of a referenced assembly on production. When it comes to windows applications its pretty easy to find the configuration file attached to the exe file and do the desired changes, but i cant seem to find it in a web site (not a web application although i think its the same there). I checked the web config but the assembly reference was not specified there. Does anyone know where to look?

Comment: Web Site or Web App project (the former is just a folder containing files/sub-folders, the latter will have a `.csproj` file)?

Comment: Its an ancient website. Moreover, I need to do the changes in production without rebuilding the code, therefor .csproj is not relevant in this case. I need the equivalent of dependentAssembly and bindingRedirect tags in app.config. Thanks